# How to create a menu with vuetify 2

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm starting to use vuetify and I want to create a menu similar to https://www.vipsanteetbeaute.com/.

However `v-app-bar` confuses me: do I need to use v-app-bar and inside use v-button and in this vbutton use v-menu ? I don't know how/where to start there is a lot of element.

This is what I done the only issue now is all on the left and I want it center

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar app color="primary">
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn text>Menu 1</v-btn>
      <v-btn text>Menu 2</v-btn>
      <v-btn text>Menu 3</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
    <v-img
      :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')"
      @click="$vuetify.goTo(0)"
      class="mr-5"
      contain
      height="48"
      width="48"
      max-width="48"
    />
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-btn text>Menu 1</v-btn>
      <v-btn text>Menu 2</v-btn>
      <v-btn text>Menu 3</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

Comment: Which version of vuetify are you using?

Comment: I'm using vuetify v2.2.11